# Trigger a sticky footer once it enters the page to reveal hidden content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having trouble creating a dynamic sticky footer that only sticks to the bottom once it enters the page then reveals a hidden surprise when you continue to scroll.

I have created this method but it is not exactly as I had hoped: http://jsfiddle.net/R3n7s/

```
jQuery(window).load(function(){
jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
   if(jQuery(window).scrollTop() + jQuery(window).height() > jQuery(document).height() - 200) {
        jQuery('h2 a').fadeIn(400);
   } else {
        jQuery('h2 a').fadeOut(400);
    }
});
});
```

This works okay but my goal is to have "This is the hidden footer that will be revealed at the end" to appear to scroll with the rest of the content and then stay put once it enters the page and then to have the surprise be revealed.

Would be grateful for any suggestions. Thank you.

**EDIT:** hope this helps to explain what I'm hoping to achieve. The above example is my fallback solution but hopefully this can be done:

[image]

**EDIT 2:** I have put together a new sample here but it's not quite right. When scrolling back down, it doesn't reverse the effect but it looks very close to what I'm hoping.

However, it's seems a bit of a hack... and it does not work on mobile. If anyone has any suggestions on how to do this better and make a conditional sticky footer, it would be great to hear your suggestions.

Here is a new sample where the text scrolls up with the page but then stops and the surprise fades in: http://jsfiddle.net/R3n7s/3/

```
jQuery(window).load(function(){
Query(window).scroll(function() {
   if(jQuery(window).scrollTop() + jQuery(window).height() > jQuery(document).height() - 300)     {
        jQuery('#footer').css({"position":"fixed", "bottom":"0"});
   } else {
        jQuery('#footer').css({"position":"relative", "bottom":"auto"});
   }
   if(jQuery(window).scrollTop() + jQuery(window).height() > jQuery(document).height() - 70) {
        jQuery('#surprise').fadeIn(600);
   } else {
        jQuery('#surprise').fadeOut(600);
   }
});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try changing the height of `'#footer'` relative to the `scrollTop` value change when the scroll reached that `jQuery(window).scrollTop() + jQuery(window).height() > jQuery(document).height() - 200` mark.

Also writing `jQuery` is tedious and hard to read for me :D. But if you're doing this because your using another library that uses the same dollar sign `'$'` alias, you can wrap your code in a jQuery function and alias `'$'` on it for brevity.

```
(function ($) {
$(window).load(function () {
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        var docViewTop = $(this).scrollTop(),
            docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(this).height(),
            docHeight = $(document).height(),
            marginBottom = parseInt($('#wrapper').css('margin-bottom'));

        if (docViewBottom >= docHeight - 200) {
            $('#footer').height((docViewBottom + marginBottom) - docHeight)
        }

        if (docViewBottom >= docHeight - 50) {
            $('h2 a').fadeIn(600);
        } else {
            $('h2 a').fadeOut(600);
        }
    })
});
})(jQuery);
```

See this [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mark_s/R3n7s/5/).

Comment: Hi Mark, really appreciate your sample. Unfortunately I don't think I was able to explain my thoughts correctly. I have found a sample website that is doing what I'm looking for: http://krystalrae.com. When you scroll, a new footer shows with FALL 2013 at the bottom. It starts to scroll, then it becomes sticky and stays there. When you scroll up more, it reveals more. If you scroll down, it gets pushed down once the main div hits the footer. I'm trying to do something like that. That said, I'm trying out your code to see if I can use how it calculates the height to improvise. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have something like this in mind? Inside of the `if` block:

```
{
  $('h2 a').fadeIn(2000);
  $('p').fadeIn(400);
} else { ... }
```

And with matching CSS:

```
#footer p {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Dklounge - sorry I may have confused my question by providing my current sample. Please allow me to add an image of what I'm hoping to achieve. The sample was my fallback as I couldn't figure out how to do this. Hope the illustration  helps communicate the goal. Thank you though.

Answer (score 0):

I did something very similar on [this website](http://www.wolfpackapp.co).  I set a data-attribute on each of the pages.  As you scroll through them, I trigger various actions based on which slide is active and finally, on the 5th slide, I slide everything up slightly to make room for the footer, and the footer appears.   If you scroll back up, the animation reverses and the footer retracts back down.

```
var activeslide = parseInt($(this).find('.active').prev().data('index'));
if (activeslide == 1) {}
if (activeslide == 2) {}
if (activeslide == 4) {}
if (activeslide == 5) { displayFooter(); }

var p = null;
function displayFooter() {
 if(this===p) {
  setTimeout(function(){
   $('footer').css({'z-index':'0'});
  },2000);
  $('footer').stop().animate({'margin-top':0},2000);
  $('.main').stop().animate({'top':0},2000);
  $('#iphone').stop().animate({'top':'75px'},2000);
  p = null;
  return false;
 } else {
  $('footer').css({'z-index':'999'});
  $('footer').stop().animate({'margin-top':'-255px'},2000);
  $('.main').stop().animate({'top':'-65px'},2000);
  $('#iphone').stop().animate({'top':'20px'},2000);
  p = this;
  return false;
 }
}
```